# Different forms of genetic algorithim

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I wrote a code that implements a simple genetic algorithm to maximize:

```
f(x) = 15x - x^2
```

The function has its maximum at 7.5, so the code output should be 7 or 8 since the population are integers.
When I run the code 10 times I get 7 or 8 around three times out of 10.
What modification should I make to further improve the algorithm and what are different types of genetic algorithms?

Here is the code:

```
from random import *
import numpy as np

#fitness function
def fit(x):
    return 15*x -x**2
#covert binary list to decimal number
def to_dec(x):
    return int("".join(str(e) for e in x), 2)

#picks pairs from the original population
def gen_pairs(populationl, prob):
    pairsl = []
    test = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for i in range(3):
        pair = []
        for j in range(2):
            temp = np.random.choice(test, p=prob)
            pair.append(populationl[temp].copy())
        pairsl.append(pair)

    return pairsl

#mating function
def cross_over(prs, mp):
    new = []
    for pr in prs:
        if mp[prs.index(pr)] == 1:
            index = np.random.choice([1,2,3], p=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3])
            pr[0][:index], pr[1][:index] = pr[1][:index], pr[0][:index]

    for pr in prs:
        new.append(pr[0])
        new.append(pr[1])

    return new


#mutation
def mutation(x):
    for chromosome in x:
        for gene in chromosome:
            mutation_prob = np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.999, .001])
            if mutation_prob == 1:
                #m_index = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3])
                if gene == 0:
                    gene = 1
                else:
                    gene = 0
    #generate initial population
    randlist = lambda n:[randint(0,1) for b in range(1, n+1)]

for j in range(10):
    population = [randlist(4) for i in range(6)]
    for _ in range(20):
        fittness = [fit(to_dec(y)) for y in population]

        s = sum(fittness)
        prob = [e/s for e in fittness]
        pairsg = gen_pairs(population.copy(), prob)

        mating_prob = []
        for i in pairsg:
            mating_prob.append(np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.4,0.6]))

        new_population = cross_over(pairsg, mating_prob)
        mutated = mutation(new_population)
        decimal_p = [to_dec(i)for i in population]
        decimal_new = [to_dec(i)for i in new_population]
        # print(decimal_p)
        # print(decimal_new)
        population = new_population
    print(decimal_new)
```

Comment: Although very interesting, I think this is off-topic for stackoverflow. You could try another site, maybe [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very typical situation with evolutionary algorithms. Success rate is a quite common metric, and 30% is a decent result.

Just an example, recently I implemented a [GP/GE solver](https://github.com/werediver/Sandbox) for [Santa Fe Trail problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Fe_Trail_problem), and it demonstrates the success rate of 30% or less.

#### How to improve success rate

*A personal interpretation of the problem based on limited experience follows.*

An evolutionary algorithm fails to find a close to global optimum solution when it converges around a local optimum or gets stuck on a great plateau, and has not enough diversity in its population to escape this trap by finding a better region.

You may try to supply your algorithm with more diversity by increasing the size of the population. Or you may look into techniques like [novelty search](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/noveltysearch/userspage/), and [quality diversity](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frobt.2016.00040/full).

By the way, here is a very nice interactive demonstration of novelty search vs. fitness search: http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/noveltysearch/userspage/demo.html